# Sending dicom files using dcmtk c-store returning JPEG lossless error

Tags: dcmtk

Trying to send dicom files using the dcmtk scu command but its returning the error below:

```
sendMessage: unable to convert dataset from 'JPEG Lossless, Non-hierarchical, Process 14' transfer syntax to 'Little Endian Explicit
```

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Tried to use the storescp switch "+xa" (accept all supported transfer syntaxes) but nothing worked:

```
sudo storescp 80 -v -aet TESTSCP +xa -od . --sort-on-study-uid st
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with storescu, not with storescp. Have you tried to use `storescu --propose-lossless`?

Comment: Yes have tried --propose lossless but its not working. Should I send the full error message?

Comment: You could try to start storescu with debug flag (-d) to get more information. Also, in case you have build the dcmtk tools yourself, you have to make sure that the jpeg library is included in storescu.